# Visual Studio unable to open port to host WCF Service

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, windows-7, wcf-client, wcf-hosting

I created a solution VS2010 C# with the WCF service, the library to get data, the service is working fine in a console application in the solution. No problem.

I have to use it on a VS2008 project (and probably later on a VS2005) for the older projects. Then I start VS2010 I get the "WCF Test Client". At this time in the VS2008, I tried to "Add a web reference" on the local machine... no result.

Then I tried to create a console application with Vs2010 to host it, I did this :

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SecurityAccessWCF.WCFSecurityService), baseAddress))
{
    // Enable metadata publishing.
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Close the ServiceHost.
    host.Close();
}
```

I get an error on the `Open()`, I get this  error "AddressAccessDeniedException - HTTP could not register URL... Your process does not have access rights" (the link provided is not clear, I'm on Win7 x64 as local admin and in a domain)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Right Click</kbd> on Visual Studio shortcut and select **Run as administrator**

This way you should be able to host it.

Alternately, you could build the project and run the resulting console application the same way under admin account.

Comment: Alternatively, if you go to the properties for the shortcut to VisualStudio, under Compatibility, you can mark it to always run as Administrator.  I ended up doing this because it was a lot easier than registering every URL that you might want to use with WCF.

Answer (score 4):

Thats a standard error meaning your application cant register the domain. Normally this is a problem on vista/windows 7 with security. Log in as administrator and run `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/Localhost user=DOMAIN\user`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) is a msdn article with more information

Comment: I read that, it's for that I said I'm administrator and I'm not in a domain what about user=DOMAIN\USer then ?

Comment: You will be on a domain. Go into computer and it will tell you which one. The user will be whatever username you logged in as. You should be able to run it as any administrator although i havent personaly tried it as anyone other than the pc administrator